# How to generate a sound with specific frequency (and be able to change the frequency)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio

I am looking for a way to generate a sound with a specific frequency in Objective-C.

And be able to change this frequency depending on other factors in order to create a sound effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try Csound, which is a programming language that defines and hence generates music.
The file format of Csound is .csd (or .orc and .sco). It defines the music score and instrument involved.
It is also available in iOS and Android platforms.
You can download it from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/csound/files/csound6/
download the "iOS" version.

In the zip, there is an example application. In this example application, there is a test case called "Simple Test 1", which reads the .csd file.